# Searching for adjectives about weights

Tags: narration, weight

I'm making a small RPG game and I'd like to not put the precise weight up for display, at least for non identified objects.

The problem is I know of only two words, light and heavy, that describe weight. Sure I could modulate them with 'very' and throw in some medium weight but it seems like an unworthy shortcut.

Could you help me out with a list of different weights for various "RPG" items (from extremely light (a mushroom) to very heavy (like a boulder) through daggers, breast plates and war axes ?

I'm sorry if this is not the place to ask questions like this here.

Valmond

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not sure this requires the expertise of an RPG community to be answered. You *might* have better luck on the [English language & usage Stack](https://english.stackexchange.com/). It also kind of seems like the RPG you're making is a video game RPG which is also off-topic here as we're a Stack for Pen and Paper/tabletop RPGs.

Comment: I recommend you also do some research using a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/) before turning to EL&U.

Comment: +1 for recommendations but -1 because I'm specifically here in the pen and paper RPG furum to ask this, in a video game forum they'd just recommend me putting the numbers in there. Guess I have to dig up my old D&D books for hints.

Comment: We also have a list of [forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) for this sort of (discussion/list-generation/brainstorming) question. And I'll note that Our Very Own [chat] is one of those forums--I'm sure you'd get great ideas picking the brains of those hanging around there any time.